# How to force Spring to run the BeanFactoryPostProcessors first when using @Conditional

Tags: java, spring

Let's say I have a bean that needs a value to be injected into one of its fields:

```
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:spring-files/my-values.properties")
public class MyArbitraryClass implements ArbitraryClass {

@Value("#{'${values.in.property.file}'.split(',')}")
private List<String> values;

private boolean myBoolean;

@PostConstruct
private void determineBoolean() {
        for (String value : values) 
            if (System.getProperty("whatever").contains(value)) 
                myBoolean = true;
}

@Override
public boolean getMyBoolean() {
        return myBoolean;
    }
}
```

I want to use the determineBoolean() method as a condition to instantiate another bean. So I implement the Condition interface:

```
public class MyCondition implements Condition {

@Override
public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        return context.getBeanFactory().getBean(ArbitraryClass.class).getMyBoolean();
    }
}
```

I componentScan MyArbitraryClass in order to make sure it instantiates first (as opposed to declaring the bean definition in a JavaConfig file):

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.package.that.contains.my.arbitrary.class")
public class Conf {

@Bean
@Conditional(MyCondition.class)
// the bean type doesn't really matter
Reader reader() throws FileNotFoundException {
    return new FileReader(new File(""));
}

@Bean
static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
}
```

The value injected to the 'values' field in MyArbitraryClass will be null, when evaluated by MyCondition. I'm pretty sure that this is because the application context that is injected into the matches() method in MyCondition, contains (at the time) the beans **before** they were processed by the BeanFactoryPostProcessors (in this case PropertySourcesPlaceHolderConfigurer).

Is there a way to get the bean in the matches() method after being processed, and all values injected into it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest is to encapsulate the search-for-existing-property in your custom condition rather than having the match logic on another bean.

With that approach you could get hold of the `Environment` directly from the exposed `context`, so your `MyCondition` would look like this:

```
public class MyCondition implements Condition {

    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        return Arrays.stream(context.getEnvironment().getProperty("values.in.property.file").split(","))
                .anyMatch(propValue -> propValue.equals(System.getProperty("whatever")));
    }
}
```